# How to apply tooltips for dc.js chart after chart is rendered

Tags: d3.js, tooltip, dc.js, crossfilter

I have multiple row charts (crossfilter + dc) and I want to customize the tooltip using d3-tip.

So basically the relevant code is:

```
rowtip = d3.tip()
    .attr('class', 'd3-tip')
    .offset([-10, 0])
    .html(function (d) { return d.key + ": "  + d.value; });

...my dc charts ...

... then at the bottom of my script tags ...

d3.selectAll('g.row').call(rowtip);
d3.selectAll('g.row').on('mouseover', rowtip.show);
```

The code seems work,  but the mouseover event doesn't get triggered automatically and the tooltips don't get displayed when the page loads.

But If I run the last line (mouseover) on the console, then everything works as expected.

[image]

So my question would be how can I make sure the mouseover event gets triggered when the page loads. I tried Jquery $(document).ready(....), but that didn't work.

It has to have something to do with the order in which the elements are loaded... I guess.  But I'm not an expert in javascript and much less in d3.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your way works fine but here is the idiomatic dc.js way to do it:

```
chart.on('pretransition.add-tip', function(chart) {
    chart.selectAll('g.row')
        .call(rowtip)
        .on('mouseover', rowtip.show)
        .on('mouseout', rowtip.hide);
});
```

The [`pretransition` event](http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/html/dc.baseMixin.html#on)  fires after the chart is rendered or redrawn. `add-tip` is an *event namespace* to avoid interfering with anything else which may be watching this event.

[`chart.selectAll`](http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/html/dc.baseMixin.html#selectAll) selects only items within the chart, to avoid accidental tooltips elsewhere in the page.

Comment: Yep. This is better. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here seems similar to your requirement, check it

http://bl.ocks.org/phil-pedruco/9032348

Comment: Thanks for the link!

Answer (score 1):

So I was able to solve this by using jquery after all. Seems a bit hacky, but it does what I need.

Basically I am forcing the call of the d3-tip function on mouseover of the html body.

```
var rowtip = d3.tip()
    .attr('class', 'd3-tip')
    .offset([-10, 0])
    .html(function(d){return d.key;}) 

$('body').on('mouseover', function(){

    d3.selectAll('g.row')
        .call(rowtip)
        .on('mouseover', rowtip.show)
        .on('mouseout', rowtip.hide);
```

});